# NodeJS able to get a buffer from C++ and modify it then send it back to C++ for post use

Tags: c++, node.js

I am trying to use NodeJS in my C++ project where I send I buffer to NodeJS, then NodeJS does some processing with this buffer. After that, I want to send the processed buffer back to C++ application.

I was trying to use "Nan" but I could only send (from NodeJS) a buffer to a C++ application and C++ application did some processing and send it back to NodeJS, but it's not what I actually want.

**buffer_example.cpp**

```
NAN_METHOD(rotate)
{
    char* buffer = static_cast<char*>(node::Buffer::Data(info[0].As<Object>()));
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent());
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t rot;
    
    if(info[1]->IsUint32())
    {
        size = info[1]->ToUint32(context).ToLocalChecked()->Value();
    }

    if(info[2]->IsUint32())
    {
        rot = info[2]->ToUint32(context).ToLocalChecked()->Value();
    }
    
   
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        buffer[i] += rot;
    }
}

NAN_MODULE_INIT(Init)
{
    Nan::Set(target, New<String>("rotate").ToLocalChecked(),
        GetFunction(New<FunctionTemplate>(rotate)).ToLocalChecked());
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Init)
```

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
// Requiring the add-on that we'll build in a moment...
const addon = require('./build/Release/buffer_example');

// Allocates memory holding ASCII "ABC" outside of V8.
const buffer = Buffer.from("ABC");
// synchronous, rotates each character by +13
addon.rotate(buffer, buffer.length, 13);
```

Can anyone of you give me a hint how to do it?

Do I need to build two different add-ons for each operation (send and retrieve)?

Comment: The simplest model for this is two separate processes and exchange data via IPC and/or files.  Your C++ program could just send an IPC message to the nodejs program which could process data and send a message back to the C++ program.  Data could even be sent via stdio.

Comment: The C++ SDK for nodejs is designed for nodejs add-ons where you create some library function in C++ that you can then call from nodejs (not the other way around).